# Packing NET4 into executable

Tags: c#, .net

Not sure if this really hits the right scope, but is it possible in C# to package a Net4 framework installer into a C# application so the first time the application is executed on a client PC, it checks to see if the correct .NET version is installed, and if not, installs it?

Comment: Why package the installer into the application instead of letting the installer do it at installtime? WIX is excellent for doing it at installtime. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html

Comment: That's a bit of a chicken and egg problem - if your application requires the .NET 4 framework and it isn't installed, how do you run the application so it can install the framework? This really is a task for the installer, not the executable itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can pack the program in an installer that first checks, and will download the installer from the web if needed.

Comment: The installer project build into visual studio can do this, though it's been a long time since I've needed to package an application that way.